# C typedef pointer to func with argument pointer to struct

Tags: c

I need to define a `typedef p*` to a function where it's argument to be `p*` to a `struct`.

```
typedef void (*tFunc_t)(pTask_t); // warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration

typedef struct Task_t {
    struct Task_t *Next; 
    tFunc_t Task; 

}Task_t, *pTask_t;
```

Since function is part of a `struct`, how can I write the `func typedef` so no more warnings by compiler?

Thank you!

Nice, thanks @R Sahu! This works smoothly.

```
struct Task_t;
    typedef void (*tFunc_t)(struct Task_t*); 
    typedef struct Task_t {
        struct Task_t *Next;
        tFunc_t Task;       
    }Task_t, *pTask_t;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use forward declaration of the `struct` to do that.

```
// Forward declaration of the struct
struct Task_t;
typedef void (*tFunc_t)(struct Task_t*);
```

You don't need to use `pTask_t` to define the `typedef` for the function pointer.